# BeautifulSoup list index out of range error with multiple .contents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I am using beautifulsoup to scrape some stock prices on yahoo finance. I currently am getting the date and the close price separately.

I am getting an indexerror: list index out of range, with the code `close = td.contents[5].text` yet the [5] is not out of range. If I was to delete all of close I could export a date data frame only if there is only one .contents in the code. How can I fix this? My code is below.

```py
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv

date_list = []
close_list = []

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/history?period1=512784000&period2=1588982400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d'
response = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

chode = soup.find('table',{'class':'W(100%) M(0)'})
for tr in chode:
    tr.find('tr')
    for td in tr:

        date = td.contents[0].text
        date_list.append(date)

        date_df = pd.DataFrame(date_list)

        close = td.contents[5].text
        close_list.append(close)

        close_df = pd.DataFrame(close_list)

    df = pd.concat( [date_df, close_df], axis=1)
    df.to_csv("TSLA.csv")
```

### Error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-1cc69b5cf5f1> in <module>
     16         date_df = pd.DataFrame(date_list)
     17 
---> 18         close = td.contents[5].text
     19         close_list.append(close)
     20 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a check for whether `len(td.contents) < 6` in your for loop and print out the corresponding `td.contents`, you'll see that there is in fact a value of `td.contents` for which the list index is out of range. Printing it out looks like this:

`[<td class="Fz(xs)" colspan="7" data-reactid="1551"><span data-reactid="1552">*Close price adjusted for splits.</span><span class="Mstart(20px)" data-reactid="1553"><span data-reactid="1554">**Adjusted close price adjusted for both dividends and splits.</span></span></td>]`

Also, because none of your code is indented properly underneath the `for tr in td`, it's hard to tell which lines you were intending to be a part of the for loop. I'm guessing what you want to do is something more like this:

```
for tr in chode:
    tr.find('tr')
    for td in tr:
        if len(td.contents) >= 6: # check that the td has enough elements
            date = td.contents[0].text
            date_list.append(date) # build the list
            close = td.contents[5].text
            close_list.append(close) # build the list

    date_df = pd.DataFrame(date_list) # create a df after the entire list is built
    close_df = pd.DataFrame(close_list) # create a df after the entire list is built

    df = pd.concat( [date_df, close_df], axis=1)
    df.to_csv("TSLA.csv")
```